# Write text with emoji using Chromedriver

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to write in a field with text containing emoji on the website web.whatsapp.com .
My project uses C#, Chromedriver , .Net 5 and Selenium.
Selenium doesn't write emojis in Chromedriver natively, so I need to write using javascript.
I can write with javascript in the field, but when I click again in the field and submit the text, the content I write disappears.
I could write a few days ago, but now I can't.
How to solve this?
Here's the code:

```
 try
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByClassName('_13NKt copyable-text selectable-text')[0].innerText=arguments[0]", "Hello");
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='app']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span/div/span/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]")).SendKeys(" ");
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='app']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/div[1]/span/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Backspace);
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@data-testid ='send']")).Click();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: How about using GeckoDriver/Firefox combo?

Comment: I know Geckodriver doesn't have this problem, however I need to use Chromedriver specifically.

Comment: So instead of SO shouldn't you raise a request with ChromeDriver/Chromium team?

Comment: Selenium/Chromedriver has this limitation in sending emoji natively. However, I already sent using the code with javascript, but now I'm facing this error.

Comment: _Chromedriver has this limitation in sending emoji natively_: You are already aware about it, what's the point in wasting time in it? FYI, it's Chromedriver limitation and nothing to do with Selenium per se...

Comment: Yes, the limitation is from the Chromedriver. However, I need to use Chromedriver

Comment: _the limitation is from the Chromedriver_: Hence SO is not the right forum, may be _**Chromedriver**_ forum. Period.